# will_paginate ordering - some columns default ASC, some DESC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I have the following in a controller to enable will_paginate sorting:

```
def sort_column
  ['name', 'scheduled', 'status'].include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "scheduled"
end
def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
end
```

These are supplemented by `<%= sortable "status", "Status" %>` at the top of a table column - clicking this will sort the table.

How can I make some columns default to ASC and some default to DESC?

#### Rationale

A text-based column works very well under ASC sorting. However, where I have columns with percentages or numbers, sometimes I want to show the best/highest first instead of requiring that the user click twice to get the column sorted the way they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

This was the original `application_helper.rb` code from Railscasts #228 and #240.

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  if direction == "desc"
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"
  else
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
  link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
end
```

I changed it to (changes on lines 1 and 4):

```
def sortable(column, title = nil, direction = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction ||= column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
end
```

This enables me to now specify a default direction in a column heading:

```
<div class="col> 
  <%= sortable "priority_number", "Priority", "desc" %> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a hash with the default sortings, grab the non-set sorting from there:

```
def sort_direction
  sort_defaults = { 'name' => 'asc', 'age' => 'desc', 'scheduled' => 'asc' }
  sort_defaults.has_value?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : sort_defaults[sort_column]
end
```

Comment: Almost there... `will_paginate` is automatically including `&direction=asc` on every URL when I hover above any column heading. If I manually remove that portion, your code works beautifully, but how can I get it to not include that `asc`, at least the first time?

Comment: Are the column heading URLs being generated by will_paginate? Can you post the code for this?

Comment: I figured it out! I'm posting the solution. Thanks a lot for your help Douglas, you got me on the right track. +1